# Loki parse JSON and sum by field

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-loki

[image: Pic of log returned]

I'm logging a JSON which is not showing up in detected fields or labels.

I'd like to parse the stderr json in my log picture, specifically capturing the field "dml_affected_rows/row_count", and sum the last 24 times it has appeared. How would I go about doing that?

EDIT: Using the pattern parser I'm able to isolate the JSON in question, like so [image: Using pattern parsing I've isolated the JSON fields]

I just want to unwrap and sum "dml_affected_rows/row_count" over time 24h). I tried but run into this error:

[image]

Now, when I look at the JSON, I see it is filled with "" escape characters. What gives? [image: Now, when I look at the JSON, i see it is filled with "" escape characters. What gives?]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse LogQL substring as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76707576/parse-logql-substring-as-json)

Comment: In your case you need `sum_over_time({job="pm2", filename=~".*server-out.*.log"}
 | regexp `(?P<json_part>\{"msg":.*)`
 | line_format {{.json_part}}
 | json | unwrap dml_affected_rows/row_count [24h])`. Not sure on label name for your field, `/` might create some troubles, but you'll need to check it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I tried to do exactly this, and I've edited my post to reflect that. I isolated the json using pattern parser, did a line format, converted to json, then tried to unwrap/sum over time. It seems to be failing due to escape characters in the JSON, although I'm not 100% sure

Comment: You could try `unwrap dml_affected_rows_row_count`, as `| json` [supposed to be sanitizing field names](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/log_queries/#parser-expression). I don't see sanitation happening in your screenshots, though; but I can't say that I'm seeing successful parsing either.

Comment: You were right, that is exactly what worked. Loki had changed the "/" character into "_". Solved!!! THANK YOU

Comment: Consider changing this question into proper question about special symbols in json field names (as first part of current question is already solved at proposed duplicate target).